# set global variable in python always return none value in main()

Tags: python, python-2.7

i got problem when i set a global variable in `main()` is always return `None` value

in `main()` i set global global variable like this:

```
def main():
    dir_path = 'None'
```

then i call function `create_directory_method` and try print the output of `dir_path`:

```
def create_directory_method(model_dir_name, i, params):
    if not os.path.exists('output/' + str(model_dir_name)):
         os.makedirs('output/' + str(model_dir_name))

x = i+1
if not os.path.exists('output/' + str(model_dir_name) + '/Data-Clone-' + str(x)):
    os.makedirs('output/' + str(model_dir_name) + '/Data-Clone-' + str(x))
with open('output/' + str(model_dir_name) + '/Data-Clone-' + str(x) + '/hyperparams.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(params, f)  
directory_path = 'output/' + str(model_dir_name) + '/Data-Clone-' + str(x)
global dir_path
dir_path = directory_path
print("path ", dir_path)
return dir_path
```

the value of `dir_path` on function is:

```
('path ', 'output/GNB/Data-Clone-1')
```

and in the `main()` i try to print `dir_path` value :

```
    print('test', dir_path)
```

but the value is always

```
('test', 'None')
```

Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: "in main() i set global global variable like this" No, you don't. That's how you create a local variable. Use `global dir_path` before the assignment.

Comment: @tobias_k it is a short answer, but I feel it is *the* answer...

Comment: def main():
    dir_path = 'None'


When you define dir_path = 'None' then obviously it return 'None'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you make an assignment in a method without using `global varname` before, Python will assume the variable to be a local variable for that method. The `main` method is no exception to that. It's just a regular method that happens to be called "main".

I assume your code looks somewhat like this:

```
def main():
    dir_path = 'None'
    create_directory_method()
    print("main", dir_path)

def create_directory_method():
    global dir_path
    dir_path = "/some/path/"
    print("method", dir_path)
    return dir_path

main()
```

Three ways to fix your problem.

1. Use `global dir_path` in main, too, to make explicit that you want to use the global variable, not define a local variable of the same name:

   ```
   def main():
       global dir_path
       dir_path = 'None'
       create_directory_method()
       print("main", dir_path)
   ```
2. Do not needlessly assign to `dir_path` in main, so that Python implicitly assumes `dir_path` to be the global one, as no local var of that name exists:

   ```
   def main():
       create_directory_method()
       print("main", dir_path)
   ```
3. Use the `dir_path` already returned by the method, and remove the `global dir_path` from the method -- you don't need it anymore:

   ```
   def main():
       dir_path = create_directory_method()
       print("main", dir_path)
   ```

I suggest you use the third approach, as this does not need any global variables at all.

Answer (score 0):

Define global variable in settings.py

```
DIR_PATH = 'documents/'
```

and use this global variable like

```
from django.conf from settings

print settings.DIR_PATH
```

**Note: Here i use django framework..**

Comment: O_o Why would you do this so complicated? And why do you introduce a whole framework in your example for something so simple?

Comment: I did that. However it's a general rule not to make things more complicated especially since the OP clearly lacks knowledge in Python hence introducing an example with *Django* is not only unnecessary but can actually be viewed as distracting and confusing.

Comment: Keep it simple, that's all. If you add Django, OpenCV, ROS, Matplotlib, PyQt etc. this only adds new layers to the problem. When a beginner looks at your post the first question that will probably come to mind would be "What is this Django thing?!" or "Do I need Django to solve this problem?". Yes, you have mentioned in your note that you are using the Django framework but to a beginner this might as well mean that he/she needs either Django or some other framework (=> "What is a framework?") in this situation.